# Two monitors, how to remove one list in one of them?

Tags: awesome-wm

I have two monitors, so when I start awesome I get a list of tags in each monitor. How to remove the list in one of them?

Ubuntu 14.04 and 3.4.15

Comment: In your `rc.lua` you will have something like `for s = 1, screen.count() do
tags[s] = awful.tag(tags.names, s, tags.layout)
end`. This loop is responsible for creating tags for each screen. Change this anyway you want

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to remove the list of tags, rather than making it so only the first monitor has it's own tags, do this:

Edit your rc.lua

find where your wiboxes are created, search for "mywibox[s].widgets" or something

change

```
mytaglist[s]
```

to

```
s == 2 and mytaglist[s] or nil
```

change the 2 to whatever your first monitor is recognized as (mine is recognized as 2 for convenience with a few weird programs...)

If you're looking to do the latter, I'm unsure of how to do it, but I could've sworn I knew how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Its a good example in the FAQ of how to set different tags and layout on different screens. Note that the number of tags, names and layout of every screen is easily altered to your liking.

```
-- {{{ Tags
tags = {
   settings = {
     { names  = { "www", "editor", "mail", "im" },
       layout = { layouts[2], layouts[1], layouts[1], layouts[4] }
     },
     { names  = { "rss",  6, 7,  "media" },
       layout = { layouts[3], layouts[2], layouts[2], layouts[5] }
}}}

for s = 1, screen.count() do
    tags[s] = awful.tag(tags.settings[s].names, s, tags.settings[s].layout)
end
-- }}}
```

*The code above is from the [FAQ](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_setup_different_tags_and_layouts_per_screen.3F).*